# Equivalent of RDBMS Sequences (autonumbers)

Tags: neo4j

How can one achieve the equivalent of RDBMS user defined sequences (auto numbering) within Neo4j?

In Oracle for instance one can define a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
  MINVALUE value
  MAXVALUE value
  START WITH value
  INCREMENT BY value
  CACHE value;
```

And to get the next number one would call `sequence_name.NEXTVAL`

The mechanism must provide for a high level of concurrency and ensure unique numbers.

Also, I noticed that the node and relationship ids follows a sequence starting from zero. Is there some way to manipulate this "built in sequences"? Sometimes when we import data from DBs from other sites we maintain the IDs (the sequence ranges are set so that IDs from different sites will never clash) - can one insert a node and supply the ID that it must take on? Or should one rather just let neo4j do its own id numbering and add a property on the node representing the other id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MERGE` statement to mimic sequences:

```
MERGE (n:Counter {name:'sequence_name'}) 
ON CREATE SET n.count=0
ON MATCH SET n.count = n.count+1
RETURN n.count as count
```

The internal ids could not be tweaked as they indicate the offset within the store file. If you need any numbering scheme, do not rely on node ids, they are a implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, will this merge request guarantee unique numbers when running in server mode with multiple clients making merge count calls concurrently?